# Angular async calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a bizarre issue happening in my Angular app and I think the async'ness of Angular is the cause but I'm not sure how I can fix it.

On `.run` I have the following:

```
app.run(function ($user, $soundcloud) {
    $user.set();
    $soundcloud.set();
});
```

and then the two services...

```
app.service('$user', ['$http',  function ($http) {    
    var currentUser;    
    this.set = function () {
        $http.get('/users/active/profile')
            .success(function (obj) {
                currentUser = obj;
            })
            .error(function () {
                console.log('ERR');
            })
    }    
    this.fetch = function () {
        return currentUser;
    }

}]);    
app.service('$soundcloud', ['$http', function ($http) {    
    var sc;    
    this.set = function () {
        $http.get('/users/active/services/soundcloud')
            .success(function (obj) {
                sc = obj;
            })
            .error(function () {
                console.log('Error fetching soundcloud feed')
            })
    }    
    this.fetch = function () {
        return sc;
    }    
}]);
```

---

The issue I'm having is that when I go to /profile and reload the page, the data returned from $soundcloud.fetch() isn't available unless I wrap $soundcloud.fetch() inside a `setTimeout()` function which obviously isn't ideal so I'm wondering where I should place `$soundcloud.set()` to also make that data available immediately on page load.

This is my controller currently:

```
app.controller('profileController', ['$scope', '$user', '$soundcloud', function ($scope, $user, $soundcloud) {

    $scope.activeUser = $user.fetch();
    $scope.activeSoundcloud = $soundcloud.fetch();

    console.log($user.fetch());
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log($soundcloud.fetch());
    },100);
}]);
```

If I take `$soundcloud.fetch()` outside of the setTimeout then I get `undefined` as the result. Where should $soundcloud.set/fetch be called in order to make both sets of data (user and soundcloud) immediately available?

Comment: hmm are `$soundcloud.set()` and `$user.set()` invoked only during the `.run()` phase?

Comment: @ryeballar yeah, they do API calls to retrieve the relevant info from the server which is then used in the app.

Comment: so it is only invoked once, so its like a configuration? for the whole application to fetch?

Comment: @ryeballar yup, the data is used throughout the app in multiple places that's why I attached those pieces of data to their own services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/uN4BYWxiCNjKPKiXTfGk?p=preview)**

One way to solve this problem is to fetch all the necessary data and then manually bootstrap the application.

To do this, create `bootstrapper.js`. You can access the built-in angular services without bootstrapping a module by `angular.injector(['ng']).invoke()` which accepts a function with dependencies that can be injected. The `urlMap` variable is simply a key value store for the settings together with each of its respective urls. You loop this `urlMap` via `angular.forEach()` and then get all settings one by one and store each settings in a `settings` variable along with each of its respective keys. Store each `$http` promise request in `promises` array to resolve it with `$q.all()`. When all promises have been resolved, call `bootstrap()` function which adds a `Settings` value in `app.settings` module and then manually bootstraps the application.

**bootstrapper.js**

```
angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(function($http, $q) {

  var urlMap = {
    $user: '/users/active/profile',
    $soundcloud: '/users/active/services/soundcloud'
  };

  var settings = {};

  var promises = [];

  var appConfig = angular.module('app.settings', []);

  angular.forEach(urlMap, function(url, key) {
    promises.push($http.get(url).success(function(data) {
      settings[key] = data;
    }));
  });

  $q.all(promises).then(function() {
    bootstrap(settings);
  }).catch(function() {
    bootstrap();
  });

  function bootstrap(settings) {
    appConfig.value('Settings', settings);

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['app', 'app.settings']);
    });
  }

});
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', [])

  .run(function(Settings) {
    if(Settings === null) {
      // go to login page or
      // a page that will display an
      // error if any of the requested
      // settings failed
    }
  })

  .controller('ProfileController', function($scope, Settings) {
    console.log(Settings);
  });
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot but what could be causing this error? https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=SettingsProvider%20%3C-%20Settings

Comment: hmm can you create a plunker that could recreate the problem? Perhaps you have mispelled Settings in the `.value()` method at `bootstrapper.js`. Did you include `bootstrapper.js`? and by the way make sure that you remove `ng-app` directive inside your html.

Comment: It was the ng-app binding that was throwing it off. I really love this technique, what would you call it? I'd like to do some research into this.

Comment: hmm there is a similar module created just for this. https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap. But I think its better to know how it works so you could tweak it to your desired implementation. So the implementation above is a version that I prefer. I don't really know how to name it.

Answer (score 0):

The result from $soundcloud.set() overrides the value from sc.

If you tried to bind the value from $soundcloud.fetch to the scope before the $soundcloud.set() is returned it binds undefined to the scope, since the var sc is not yet defined. When $soundcloud.set() set the sc field, the scope variable will never get notified since it only got the undefined value and know nothing about sc.

The easiest sollution is to create a wrapper object that will never be removed. Something like this.

```
app.service('$soundcloud', ['$http', function ($http) {    
var sc = {};    // define an object instead of undefined
this.set = function () {
    $http.get('/users/active/services/soundcloud')
        .success(function (obj) {
            sc.soundcloud = obj; // write to a field on the object, 
                                 // do not override sc, since sc is already returned
        })
        .error(function () {
            console.log('Error fetching soundcloud feed')
        })
}    
this.fetch = function () {
    return sc;
}    
}]);
```

When you use the result of $soundcloud.fetch() you need to refer to the soundcloud field. At least it will always get updated when $soundcloud.set is called

Comment: I'm still getting undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about it being a problem with the asynchronicity.

1. The code in `.run()` triggers an asynchronous `.get()`.
2. Before the result comes back, and the callback passed to `.success()` is run, you run `fetch()`. As such, `fetch()` returns an undefined `sc`.
3. You then `console.log()` this, hence you see undefined.
4. The promise gets resolved with the data from your `.get()`, and you assign `sc` to the result.

The approach **@Andre Paap** has just outlined is a good one - essentially by creating a blank reference object and updating one of its properties on the callback (rather than overwriting the reference completely), you can still assign this to the scope, and angular will 'magically' update the view once it's populated (using the data binding). *However*, if you `console.log()` the result immediately, you'll still see the same thing.

In other words, if you had this inside your service:

```
var currentUser = {};    
this.set = function () {
    return $http.get('/users/active/profile')
        .success(function (obj) {
            currentUser.name = obj.name;
        })
        .error(function () {
            console.log('ERR');
        })
}
```

And this in your template:

```
<span ng-show="currentUser.name"> Hello {{currentUser.name}}! </span>
```

Then putting this in your controller would result in the above span showing up correctly once the `set()` call has returned:

```
$scope.currentUser =  $user.fetch()
// NOTE: the below would still log undefined:
console.log($scope.currentUser.name) //<- undefined.
```

If you wanted to run some code only after the `.set()` call has been returned, then you can take advantage of the fact that `$http` methods return promises, like so:

```
$user.set().then(function(){
  // This code runs *after* the call has returned.
  $scope.currentUser = $user.fetch()
  console.log($scope.currentUser.name) //<- "Ed"
});
```

Comment: I've implemented what you've posted but now I get cannot read property 'then' of undefined?

Comment: The result of .set() isn't a promise result is it?

Comment: Ah sorry, put 'return'  before $http so that the promise is returned

Comment: I updated the code to have this - I'm used to coffeescript where the last statement gets returned automatically. One final note, I also normally use `.then(successFunction, failFunction)` rather than `.success()` and `.error()`, but I think they act the same and return a promise.