# One time async data load in angular factory - convention ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a simple app for displaying (read-only) employee information.  I would like to load the info from JSON once only. Not sure what the convention is around this in the angular factory.

I know that one solution is to but the JSON file in a javascript file and load it as a js file (but I would want to keep the file as JSON).

I guess I could also wrap the http call in a promise, and change the return accordingly.

Is there a way of doing this without changing the return? Block on the employee load ?

```
 .factory('Employees', ['$http', function($http) {

  var employees = $http.get('res/employees.json').then(function(response){
        return response.data;  // This is async so won't return right away
    });

  // This way works (since not async)
  // var employees = [
  //   {
  //       "id": 232,
  //       "name": "Bob"
  //   }];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return employees; // This will return empty before employees is loaded
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: what you mean by I would like to load the info from JSON once only? If you want to laod only once then you need to call this service only one time.

Comment: No, you cannot block. Always returning a promise (which might already be resolved) is very fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a wrong implementation of the promise pattern.  Your 'employee' service should return a promise also that gets initialized and then returns the same resolved promise upon subsequent requests.  Something like this:

```html
.factory('Employees', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {

  var _deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get('res/employees.json')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           // this callback will be called asynchronously
           // when the response is available

           _deferred.resolve(data);

         })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           // called asynchronously if an error occurs
           // or server returns response with an error status.

           _deferred.reject("Error");
        });
     };

  return {
    getEmployees: function(){
      return _deferred.promise;
    }
  }

}]);


.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'Employees', function($scope, Employees) {
 
 $scope.employees = [];

 $scope.employees = Employees.getEmployees();

}]);
```

$scope.employees will initially be an empty array until the promise is resolved.  Also, this code does not have error recovery.

Comment: The `employees` variable in the OP's code, actually returns a promise. The OP's intention from the start is to load the `employees.json` once. Your code suggests that each call to `getEmployees()` must request for `employees.json` everytime.

Comment: You could consider using another promise ($q) that gets resolved with the initial $http request and then returns the same resolved promise thereafter.  I edited the code sample to reflect.

Comment: There is no need to use `$q`, `$http.get()` returns a promise wherein a promise has a method `then()` which also returns a promise.

Comment: The 2nd promise wrapper is so you don't make additional requests for the same $http.  When this factory is first instantiated, it triggers the intial $http request.  Thereafter, it will return the resolved 2nd promise which is already resolved.

Comment: The OP's answer is already doing what you're doing without the `$q` service. Additionally, you are creating another problem, it should return `_deferred.promise`.

Comment: @ryeballer: you're correct, I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Promise is a property not a function. The `$q` service usage is really redundant in this case.

Comment: It is redundant indeed. Put what $http.get('res/employees.json') returns in a var and return it from getEmployees function.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution that might work for you is to fetch the data and **[manually bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)** your application with an appended `value` or `service` of the fetched data. There are already built solutions for this kind of problem, one is called the [**`angular-deferred-bootstrap`**](https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap) and another is a **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219132/angular-async-calls)** I made just a month ago. Both are making use of the AngularJS lifecycle in manually bootstrapping the application, using [**`angular.bootstrap()`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap). Note that when you are manually bootstrapping your application you need to remove the `ng-app` directive.